# Who is the "$\Pi_2$-soundness" version of the first incompleteness theorem due to?

Tags: logic, reference-request, computability, proof-theory, incompleteness

I'm trying to remember who is responsible for the following well-known weak version of the first incompleteness theorem:

> Suppose $T$ is a c.e. consistent $\Pi_2$ extension of Robinson's $\mathsf{Q}$ (or any c.e. consistent theory which interprets such). Then $T$ is incomplete.

*Proof*: we can computably enumerate the indices of $T$-provably-total computable functions, and then diagonalize against these; by $\Pi_2$-soundness of $T$, the result is a total computable function which is clearly not $T$-provably total. $\quad\Box$

Essentially the same idea gives a version of the second incompleteness theorem for $1$-consistency in place of consistency. Harvey Friedman writes about this [here](https://bpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/u.osu.edu/dist/1/1952/files/2021/09/IncompChinese090821.pdf) (page 14), and says that its original provenance is a bit murky:

> "The origins of G2/1-con = G2 for 1-consistency are rather
> unclear. Lev Beklemishev has a paper in the 1980's about this,
> but it probably was first proved much earlier, perhaps when the
> notion of provably recursive functions of a theory first came
> into common use. That is probably in the 1950s with G. Kreisel.
> Some of the early proof theorists of that period are good
> candidates for having known about the directly straightforward
> proof of G2/1-con that we sketch now. (I don't know if Kreisel
> had this)."